# Javascript cannot be found to be loaded from the JSP/controller path

Tags: java, javascript, spring

When I try to load a js file externally I keep getting a 404 error in the firebug NET console. The JSP can't seem to be detecting the js file and I have tried many combinations with no luck, also searched the net without any real progress, can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Web XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>GreenwhichProject</display-name>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Workspace Path Directory Structure Picture

http://img26.imageshack.us/i/workspacepath.jpg/

```
PROJECT
 |
 WebContent
    |
    js
      |_jquery-1.5.js

   WEB-INF
      |_dispatcher-servlet.xml
      |_web.xml
       jsp
         |_OrderTaxi.jsp
```

Additionally this is how a normal controller function looks like

```
@RequestMapping(value="/taxiOrder/loadOrderTaxiServicePage.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showOrderTaxiServicePage(ModelMap model){
    return "orderTaxi";
}
```

So when I have to access a page it will usually be the /"controllerName"/"functionHtmName"

dispatcher-servlet.xml has a view resolver if it will be useful for figuring out the problem

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

Additionally this is how I am looking for the JS in my JSP file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please try <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.5.js"></script>

Comment: Great I'll post it as answer :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18572053/3737468 Repost and solution here, Worked like a charm that mvc:...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `<script type="text/javascript" src="/[your_apps_contextroot]/js/jquery-1.5.js"></script>` with `your_apps_contextroot` being the context root you defined for your application (might be the war file's base name by default).