# How to give path for external javascript file inside WEB-INF in JSP

Tags: java, spring-mvc, static-resource

I am developing Spring web application.
my application package structure is

```
web/----|
        |WEB-INF/
             |-jsps/
             |-scripts/
             |-styles/
             |-web.xml
```

It is `Spring MVC` & `maven` based project. I have to use the external `javascript` file in `jsp` file. 
if I use `<script src="/scripts/MyFile.js"/>` is not working as the resource is inside `WEB-INF`.
I have tried so many ways but I could not find solution.
So could you please tell me how to access `external javascript` file from `JSP` file.

**Note:** I cant change my `Directory Structure` as it is specification. And I should only use external javascript files.

So could you please provide solution. Thanks in adavnce.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure (see: [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources)):

```xml
<mvc:resources mapping="/scripts/**" location="/WEB-INF/scripts/" />
```

Then reference it like:

```xml
<script type="text/javascript" src="${context}/scripts/MyFile.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Some other way:

```
  src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jscript/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.js"
```

We have been using this in our projects. Working perfectly.